# Non-void function error

Tags: cs50

I'm trying to compile this program in c (for a cs50 online class), and keep getting the following error:

*fifteen.c:233:1: error: control may reach end of non-void function [-Werror,-Wreturn-type]
}*

I'm not asking about the logic of my code, but more looking for the syntax error that I've been missing for the last hour. Code is below. Thanks!

```
bool move(int tile)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < d - 1; i++){

        for (int j= 0; j < d - 1; j++){

            if (tile == board[i][j]){

                if (board[i+1][j] == tile){
                    board[i+1][j] = 0;
                    board[i+1][j] = tile;
                    return true;
                                        }
                else if (board [i-1][j] == 0){
                    board[i-1][j] = tile;
                    board [i-1][j] = 0;
                    return true;
                                        }
               else if (board [i][j+1] == 0){
                    board[i][j+1] = tile;
                    board [i][j+1] = 0;
                    return true;
                                        }
               else if (board [i][j-1] == 0){
                    board[i][j-1] = tile;
                    board [i][j-1] = 0;
                    return true;
                                      }
    }
    return false;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Correct your indenting and it may become clear. remember the compile doesn't know what values everything will have at runtime, so it won't make any assumptions for you (like assuming one of your if statements will always be true)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is saying that your method can reach the end without *returning* a value. This is happening in this case because your brackets are out of place.

Try the following:

```
bool move(int tile) {
     for (int i = 0; i < d - 1; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < d - 1; j++) {
              if (tile == board[i][j]) {
                  if (board[i+1][j] == tile) {
                      board[i+1][j] = 0;
                      board[i+1][j] = tile;
                      return true;
                  }
                  else if (board [i-1][j] == 0){
                      board[i-1][j] = tile;
                      board [i-1][j] = 0;
                      return true;
                  }
                  else if (board [i][j+1] == 0){
                      board[i][j+1] = tile;
                      board [i][j+1] = 0;
                      return true;
                  }
             }
             else if (board [i][j-1] == 0){
                 board[i][j-1] = tile;
                 board [i][j-1] = 0;
                 return true;
             }
         }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Notice, you were missing the end-bracket for the outer if-statement before its else-if compliment.

Comment: Boom! It now compiles, igoldthwaite! I will accept answer as soon as it lets me. It's crazy how such a minor mistake can cause you to beat your head into the wall for an hour. I'm a rookie, as you can tell.